# Firestore Database Rules - "Create" Rule Not Working for Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Database Rules for Documents Created with HTTP Cloud Function**

The attached image shows two things:

1. Screenshot of Firestore database collection with one document that was created via http cloud function
2. Screenshot of Firestore 2.0 rules.

**Rule**
The rule `allow create: if request.resource.data.replyTo == "hello";` was written to prevent any document from being created unless 'replyTo' == "hello".

**Question**
Why was the document allowed to be created when 'replyTo' == 'john@smith.com' ?

[image: Screenshot of Two Things: Database Collection and Document, and Database Rules]

Comment: Firebase security rules only apply to the client-side SDKs. They do not apply to operations in the console, or to operations that use the Admin SDK. How did you create the document?

Comment: Document was created by an HTTP cloud function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud Firestore Security Rules is only for the Android, iOS, and Web client libraries. Not for server side(cloud functions using firebase admin SDK).

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview

> For mobile and web client libraries, use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore Security Rules to handle serverless authentication, authorization, and data validation. Learn how to secure your data for the Android, iOS, and Web client libraries with Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

Comment: Wow.  Rules do not apply when cloud functions are involved?  That should be displayed in a large red box on the firestore docs "Secure and Validate Data".  I spent 6 hours on this yesterday.

Comment: Exactly. I think so too.

Comment: It should be applied to cloud function. I am using cloud function as an API server. All of data should be controlled at server side.

Comment: So if I'm using the same pattern (Cloud function reading/writing to Firebase collections), what rules should I use?  These cloud functions are the *only* way I'm touching Firebase.  Do I just `allow:  if false;` on `{document=**}`?