# Firestore rules working in simulator but not using the admin sdk

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using Firestore in Datastore mode solely from the backend (app engine standard - node.js)

I specified those simple rules in the Firestore console:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if false;
   }

   match /users/{userID} {

           function currenciesValid() {
           return request.resource.data.currencies.gold.balance is int && 
         request.resource.data.currencies.gold.balance >= 0 &&
         request.resource.data.currencies.mana.balance is int &&
         request.resource.data.currencies.mana.balance >= 0
       }

       allow write: if currenciesValid();
   }
 }
}
```

When running in the simulator (create and update) the rules work as expected.

However, after deploy it has no affect on the app and I'm able to create a gold balance of 1.5 for example.

Any idea what's going on?

My document path is users/user_{uid} where uid is the firebase auth uid.

Just for clarification I actually am connecting from my computer to Firestore. Haven't tested the rules from app engine instance yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore Database Rules - "Create" Rule Not Working for Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191098/firestore-database-rules-create-rule-not-working-for-cloud-functions)

Comment: Wow, that's so annoying and incredibly unclear! Thanks @zkohi